# Magento 2 - Categories not display when Page Cache is on

Tags: magento2, php, layout, category, magento2.2

I have a very strange issue on Magento 2.2.2, if I enable the **Page Cache** (Full page caching - FPC) the top navigation is not display anymore.

What I can do?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento uses esi tags to render nav menu when varnish is enabled. ESI tags does not getting rendered without varnish. Most probably you have varnish enabled. Goto Stores=>Configuration=>System=>Full Page Cache. Check caching application is set to built-in cache.

Comment: Indeed is related with the Varnish cache, I remove all ttl attributes from default.xml in the theme folder and everything seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to keep enable varnish and also want to display categories, then only disable fullpage cache.

```
bin/magento cache:disable full_page
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps;

1. Clear browser cache and local storage
2. Reset indexers by running following

> php bin/magento indexer:reset

3. Reindex indexers by running following

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

4. Clean cache

> php bin/magento cache:clean

5. Flush Cache

> php bin/magento cache:flush

6. Give required permission to folders

> chmod 777 -R var pub generated